# Can't install PG rubygem on Centos

Tags: centos, postgresql

I am attempting to run `gem install pg` on my Centos VPS but am getting

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
```

I have installed postgres 9.3 as you can see here (`yum list installed | grep postgres`)

```
postgresql-libs.x86_64              8.4.13-1.el6_3                     @base
postgresql93.x86_64                 9.3.1-1PGDG.rhel6                  @pgdg93
postgresql93-devel.x86_64           9.3.1-1PGDG.rhel6                  @pgdg93
postgresql93-libs.x86_64            9.3.1-1PGDG.rhel6                  @pgdg93
postgresql93-server.x86_64          9.3.1-1PGDG.rhel6                  @pgdg93
```

Comment: Please refer this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu

Comment: Already installed postgresql-devel (as the post suggests). You can see it is installed in my output above

Comment: Then try to rebuild using --with-pg-config option which specifies pg_config path of your PG installation

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution and restart your session

```
export PATH="/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH"
```

or try

```
yum install libpqxx-devel
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the postgresql libs using yum:

```
yum install postgresql-libs
```

This should install the referred library so you can try to install the gem again.

Comment: For this, you would actually need postgresql-devel, but that installs the stock CentOS / RHEL provided version of those libraries and headers (8.4.x). Which is probably not what this person is looking for.